# Trouble with a terminal command using expect to send this

Tags: awk, grep, send, expect

I'm having a problem with the command send in expect script.
I've never used the expect before, so there are so many peculiarity about it that I don't know, mainly about syntax.

Actually it catches the cpu usage btw.

> top -n 10 -d 0.01 | awk 'BEGIN{FS="[,%]"; printf "(" }/^Cpu/{
>   gsub(/[^0-9.,]+/,"",$7); gsub(/^3949/,"",$7); printf $7" + "}
>   END{print 0") / 10"}' | bc

What I would like to do is: with expect, using the command send. I want pass that string by the script.

I'm trying on this way:

```
#!/bin/expect
set timeout 20
set user [lindex $argv 0]
set password [lindex $argv 1]
set host [lindex $argv 2]
set prompt "$ "

;

proc gestat { } {
        ;
        send -- "echo -n 'MEMORY_FREE: ' && free -t | grep 'buffers/cache' | awk '{print \$4/(\$3+\$4) * 100}'\r"
        send -- "top -n 10 -d 0.01 | awk \'BEGIN{FS='[,%]'; printf '(' }/^Cpu/{ gsub(/[^0-9.,]+/,'',\$7); gsub(/^3949/,'',\$7); printf \$7' + '} END{print 0') / 10'}\' | bc\r"

        return
}

;

spawn ssh $user@$host

while (1) {
        expect {
                "(yes/no)? " {
                        send -- "yes\r"
                }

                "password: " {
                        send -- "$password\r"
                }

                "$prompt" {
                        gestat
                        break
                }
        }
}

expect "$prompt"
        send -- "exit\r"

expect eof
```

But the send does not work. The error is:

> invalid command name ",%"
>       while executing ",%"
>       (procedure "gestat" line 4)

I guess it would be because the expect "parser". But I really don't know.
Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Seems like a bazooka to kill a fly =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since expect is an extension of Tcl, the `[]` characters are special in double quoted strings. You'll need to protect them.

Additionally, you'll get in trouble in the second call to awk -- you cannot embed single quotes in a single quoted string.

You need to use Tcl's `{}` quoting -- braces in Tcl quote strings like the shell uses single quotes:

```
send -- {echo -n 'MEMORY_FREE: ' && free -t | grep 'buffers/cache' | awk '{print $4/($3+$4) * 100}'}
send -- \r
send -- {top -n 10 -d 0.01 | awk 'BEGIN{FS="[,%]"; printf "(" }/^Cpu/{ gsub(/[^0-9.,]+/,"",$7); gsub(/^3949/,"",$7); printf $7 " + "} END{print 0 ") / 10"}' | bc}
send -- \r
```

Comment: Thank you.
I've  solved it in this way, but yours is cleaner.

        send -- "echo -n 'MEMORY_FREE: ' && free -t | grep 'buffers/cache' | awk '{print \$4/(\$3+\$4) * 100}' && printf '\n' && echo -n 'CPU_FREE: ' && top -n 10 -d 0.01 | awk \'BEGIN{FS=\"\[,%\]\"; printf \"\(\" }/^Cpu/{ gsub\(/\[^0-9.,\]+/,\"\",\$7\); gsub\(/^3949/,\"\",\$7\); printf \$7\" + \"} END{print 0\"\) / 10\"}\' | bc\r"